# How to do facebook login integration in nuxt vue js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I am a beginner in nuxt vue js. I dont know how to integrate facebook login in nuxt vue js. I have tried with javascript sdk. but it gives error as FB is not defined when trying to login

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Nuxt Auth.

Heres the documentation part where it mentions facebook: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/facebook/

I recommend reading the documentation from beginning, tho, as it will help you understand how Nuxt Auth works before trying to simply implement facebook auth.

Answer (score -1):

If u want to add facebook login in your app try that:

1. Install the fb-sdk package using npm or yarn:

```
npm install fb-sdk
```

2. Create a new file called `fb-sdk.js` in the `plugins` directory of your Nuxt.js project. In this file, configure the Facebook SDK by initializing it with your Facebook App ID:

```
// plugins/fb-sdk.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { load } from 'fb-sdk';

export default async ({ app }) => {
  const sdk = await load();
  sdk.init({
    appId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v12.0'
  });

  Vue.prototype.$fb = sdk;
};
```

Replace 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID' with your own Facebook App ID. You can obtain the App ID by creating a new app on the Facebook Developer platform.

3. In your nuxt.config.js file, add the fb-sdk.js plugin to the plugins array:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/fb-sdk.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Ensure that the `mode` is set to `client` to load the Facebook SDK only on the client-side.

4. Create a new Vue component called `FacebookLogin.vue` or use an existing component. In this component, include the Facebook login button:

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <div id="fb-login-button" class="fb-login-button" data-width="300" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    // Render the Facebook login button
    this.$fb.XFBML.parse();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
/* Style the Facebook login button as needed */
</style>
```

In this example, we use the official Facebook login button provided by the Facebook SDK. You can customize the appearance of the button using CSS.

5. Use the `FacebookLogin` component in any desired location within your Nuxt.js project, such as a login page or a user profile page.

That's it! With these steps, you have integrated Facebook login into your Nuxt.js application using the Facebook JavaScript SDK. When the Facebook login button is clicked, users will be prompted to log in with their Facebook credentials.